# Lists in Tabular Environment

Tags: latex, pdflatex

So I'm writing up a CV and I would like to use the nifty `itemize` environment to list some things within a `tabular` environment.  Unfortunately, things end up looking a bit 
[image: this], which isn't at all what I want.  Specifically, I want to the itemize environment to hug closely to "BIG COMPANY NAME" so that it appears as "Software Development Intern" does, and likewise at the bottom.  My current code looks a bit like so:

```
\textsc{May 2010 to Aug 2010}
    & Software Development Intern  \\
    & \textsc{BIG COMPANY NAME} \\
    & \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \item item1
        \item item2
    \end{itemize} \\
    & \small{Cool Details}\\
```

Buuut it's not doing the job at all.  Any suggestions, Latex gurus?

Comment: This is a hack, but you can just add a `\vspace{-0.1in}` before the `\begin{itemize}` command. See if it works. Also, you might get better answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `paralist` which defines among others the `compactitem` environment (which is a compact itemize). It also  redefines itemize that way, but there are options to leave it, like `olditem`.
In your case I would just load

```
\usepackage[olditem,oldenum]{paralist}
```

and use `\begin{compactitem} ... \end{compactitem}` inside tables.